# matching id's of two array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have 2 array $dizi1 and $dizi2. And these are like this.

```
$dizi1 = [
[
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'özkan',
  'surname' => 'özdemir',
],
[
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'çağrı',
    'surname' => 'uğurel',
],
[
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'can',
    'surname' => 'tokay'
],
[
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => 'lütfü',
    'surname' => 'uzun'
]
];

$dizi2 = [
[
    'id' => 2,
    'birthday' => 1993
],
[
    'id' => 3,
    'birthday' => 1990
],
[
    'id' => 4,
    'birthday' => 1989
],
[
    'id' => 1,
    'birthday' => 1987
]
];
```

and this is what i want

```
istenenDizi = [
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'özkan',
    'surname' => 'özdemir',
    'birthday' => 1987,
]
];
```

i reseaxrh a lot bu i cant find a algortihm to do this. I will also create two excel table and i am gonna use this. Can you please help me how can i do this? 
Thanksss!

Comment: use `foreach`, where are the codes?

Comment: These are all codes. I printed it as Json.

Comment: thats it? not even a smidge of trying with foreach? by the way you don't need an algorithm, you can just start with a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `foreach()`, `array_search()`,`array_column()` like below:-

```
$istenenDizi = [];

foreach($dizi1 as $dizi1){

  $istenenDizi[$dizi1['id']] = $dizi1;
  $istenenDizi[$dizi1['id']]['birthday'] = $dizi2[array_search($dizi1['id'],array_column($dizi2,'id'))]['birthday'];
}
$istenenDizi = array_values($istenenDizi);

print_r($istenenDizi);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1000838

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Answer (score 2):

As you second array unsorted, you can sort it first. Then combine the two array by items.  [Demo](https://eval.in/1000848).

```
usort($dizi2, function($a, $b){ return $a['id'] > $b['id'];});
foreach($dizi1 as $k=>$v){
    $v['birthday'] = $dizi2[$k]['birthday'];
    $result[] = $v;
}
```